# PARS squash game

Tags: python-3.x

below is my code that simulates a PARS scored squash game:

```
import random
def game(ra, rb):
    prob_a = ra / (ra + rb)

    points_a = 0
    points_b = 0

    winning_score = 11

    while points_a < winning_score and points_b < winning_score:
        prob = random.random()
        if prob < prob_a:
            points_a += 1
        else:
            points_b += 1
    return(points_a, points_b)

game(70,30)
```

It works fine, but I'm not sure how to make sure that player a or b has to win by 2 clear points.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're asking. What exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `while` statement to keep the game going while the score is too close.

```
while (points_a < winning_score and points_b < winning_score) or abs(points_a - points_b) < 2
```